# how to create a stored procedure by validate data from one table and insert data into another table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a stored procedure by validating data between tables profilelogs and profilelogs_arch using sessionid and profileid. if the session id and profileid being different, then the insertion of data into profilelog_arch should be carried on, else the insertion is not

Comment: You can use if not exists and put your condition into it.

Comment: can you please add code for that to create a stored procedure, as I am new to sql server.

Comment: Can you provide your complete schema for tables.

Comment: CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_profilelogs](
 [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 [profileid] [int] NULL,
 [viewtype] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [ipaddress] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [referal] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [browsername] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [browserversion] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [countryname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [regionname] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [city] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [zipcode] [nchar](10) NULL,
 [pagename] [varchar](max) NULL,
 [router_log] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 [iscrawler] [nchar](10) NULL,
 [logtime] [datetime] NULL,
 [sessionid] [varchar](50) NOT NULL)ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Create prcedure sp_archiveprofile_logs
as
IF EXISTS ( SELECT PROFILEID,SESSIONID FROM  tbl_profilelogs as main exists 
(SELECT PROFILEID,SESSIONID FROM  tbl_profilelogs_arch as arch where arch.profileid<>main.profileid and arch.sessionid<>main.sessionid))
begin
insert into tbl_profilelogs_arch select * from tbl_profilelogs
end
```

Above code is just a logic, please do the required changes based on the requirement.

Thanks

Comment: Oh yeah.. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Is there any way to insert data from one table to another in Stored Procedure without any conditions

Comment: Just remove the condition in the above procedure.  It will insert data from one table to another table directly when you execute the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Create prcedure sp_archiveprofile_logs

as

insert into tbl_profilelogs_arch select * from tbl_profilelogs

end

Answer (score 0):

```
Create prcedure sp_archiveprofile_logs
as
IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
            FROM  tbl_profilelogs as main exists 
               (SELECT 1 
                FROM  tbl_profilelogs_arch as arch 
                WHERE arch.profileid<>main.profileid 
                AND arch.sessionid<>main.sessionid
               )
          )
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO tbl_profilelogs_arch select * from tbl_profilelogs
        END
```

Try it...

Comment: I want to simply insert the whole data from the table tbl_profilelogs to  tbl_profilelogs_arch without any conditions and truncate the table tbl_profilelogs

Comment: Insert into tablename select * from tablename1 ... its ti simple

Comment: yes I tried that, But while exec the stored procedure it shows an error as "Msg 201, Level 16, State 4, Procedure sp_archiveprofile_logs, Line 2
Procedure or function 'sp_archiveprofile_logs' expects parameter '@viewtype', which was not supplied."

Comment: if shown this type of error then you have to pass parameter ALTER PROCEDURE sp_archieveprofile_logs as @viewtype varchar(max) as If Exists....... Just Like that

Comment: EXEC sp_archieveprofile_logs @viewtype= ' Your Value put here '  and then execute

Comment: Procedure or function 'sp_archiveprofile_logs' expects parameter '@viewtype', which was not supplied.